# How to receive auth token from header with Java and Json

Tags: java, json, oauth-2.0, token, postman

I have a bunch of GET, POST, PUT etc calls.

I need to add the ability to receive a token.

Currently I receive a request with a Json body.

I need to add an additional header for auth but I have no idea how to receive that. For example, I have a POST request using this formatting:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/house")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public House createHouse(House house);
```

How do I enhance that to receive an additional header for auth?

Perhaps I need to add to this question...

How do I add this in Postman such that I pick it up correctly in the code? I'm basically struggling to make the link betweek adding the token in a request and picking it up on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
@Path("/house")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public House createHouse(House house, @Context HttpHeaders headers){
   String auth = headers.getRequestHeader("auth-header").get(0);
}
```

Comment: is "my-auth-header" a variable i choose when i make the request?

Comment: Basically, if I add header in postman: Authorization, how do I receive that? Unless I am using the wrong header in Postman..?

Comment: 404 not found, means your request doesnt match the controller method. Which Jax-rs implementation are you using?

Comment: these are what i'm using if it helps:
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-cors</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I basically just have an interface with this method and another class that implements it. i'm not sure i'm understanding your question fully!

Comment: try removing @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })

Comment: still the same - WebApplicationExceptionMapper    | 77 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs - 3.2.0 | javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 404 Not Found

Comment: did it work ok, without the Context and HeaderParams annotations?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use @HeaderParam

```
public House createHouse(House house, @HeaderParam("my-auth-header") String authHeader){...}
```